# Find a matching text and replace next two lines in unix

Tags: unix, sed, find

I have a file like this

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
```

I want to find bbb and replace next 2 lines with zzz. The final outcome should be

```
aaa
bbb
zzz
zzz
eee
```

I tried sed, I can do for one line. Not sure how to do it for 2 lines.
Please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can the two lines after bbb also contain bbb?

Comment: no. its only once

Comment: If bbb appears multiple times how can this be achived?

Comment: I suggest to start a new question with a corresponding example.

Comment: @PrasadJayathilake Both answers do the replacement for each occurrence of `bbb`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed '/bbb/,+2{ /bbb/b; s/.*/zzz/ }' file
```

With awk:

```
awk '/bbb/{print; getline; print "zzz"; getline; print "zzz"; next}1' file
```

Answer (score 2):

You can choose sed or awk:

```
sed '/bbb/{n;N;s|.*|zzz\
zzz|}' file
```

```
awk 'flag{print "zzz";flag--;next};/bbb/{flag=2};1' file
```

If you go for sed, make sure not to change the single-quotes to double-quotes.

Comment: sed - replaced two lines but the lines display as zzzzzz.
-aaa
-bbb
-zzzzzz
-eee

. Grep solution worked fine

Comment: If bbb appears multiple times how to do ?

Comment: @PrasadJayathilake If your sed does that you probably changed the single-quotes to double-quotes. Try the command as I wrote it. There is no grep solution, maybe you meant awk. For multiple `bbb`, I recommend opening a new question with more details, although even those may be fine.

Comment: Perhaps `sed '/bbb/{n;N;s/.*/zzz/p}' file`?

Comment: @potong That works indeed, but I'm very surprised. I thought `.*` would get the whole pattern space (firstline+\n+secondline) and replace it by `zzz` instead of doing it on each line. EDIT: Nevermind, now I see the `p` at the end, which will cause `zzz` to be printed once more.